# Criar Database usando Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Existe alguma forma de criar uma nova database direto da minha aplicação?
Estou usando o Asp.Net MVC5 C#, Fluent Nhibernate e o PostgreSQL.

Obs.: Eu já consigo acessar minhas tabelas através da aplicação, o que eu precisa é gerar uma nova database atravez da aplicação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Nhibernate não gera nova Database, porém é possível gerar novas DB adicionando a referência do Npgsql.

Com isso agora podemos executar:

```
// 1. Connect to server to create database:
const string connStr = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=enter;";

// 2. Connect to server to create table:
const string connStr2 = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=enter;Database=testDb";


var m_conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr); // db connction
var m_conn2 = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr2); // table connection

// creating a database in Postgresql
m_createdb_cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  \"testDb\" " +
                               "WITH OWNER = \"postgres\" " +
                               "ENCODING = 'UTF8' " +
                               "CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;", m_conn);

// creating a table in Postgresql
m_createtbl_cmd = new NpgsqlCommand
   {
   CommandText ="CREATE TABLE table1(ID CHAR(256) CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY, Title CHAR)"
   };

   m_createtbl_cmd.Connection = m_conn2;

 // 3.. Make connection and create

    // open connection to create DB
    m_conn.Open();
    m_createdb_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    m_conn.Close();

    // open connection to create table
    m_conn2.Open();
    m_createtbl_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    m_conn2.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso assim:

```
private static FluentConfiguration Configure()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                        .ExposeConfiguration(x => {
                            x.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web");
                            x.SetProperty("generate_statistics", "true");
                        })
                        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                        .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Conexao"))
                                        #if DEBUG
                                        .ShowSql()
                                        #endif
                                        )
                                        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(typeof(MapCidade).Assembly));
        }

/// <summary>
/// Método utilizado para criar o Banco de Dados do Sistema.
/// </summary>
public static void GenerateDatabase()
{
    var c = Configure();
    c.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
     .Create(false, true))
     .BuildConfiguration();
}
```

Lembre-se de colocar os usings para o fluent.

Comment: Assim só esta zerando a base já criada? Como você fez para setar o nome da nova base?